# Creating a network load balancer in AWS with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to get a network load balancer to balance requests between two public subnets in two AZs.  The following code creates all the resources needed, but a simple GET command to the load balancers DNS name hangs.  The Monitoring for the load balancer shows nothing.

One strange thing is that the web console shows that there is no security group for this load balancer, but the aws cli shows the load balancer has a security group.

```
    aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --names web-lb
    
...
                ],
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    "sg-070b4e29b0e44d64e"
                ],
...
```

Do I have an error in my terraform code, or is this a bug in terraform?

## Terraform code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "balanced_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "balanced_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public_route_table" {
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.balanced_gateway.id
  }
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "aws_route_table_assc_a" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.publicA.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "aws_route_table_assc_b" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.publicB.id
}

resource "aws_lb" "external" {
  subnets = [aws_subnet.publicA.id, aws_subnet.publicB.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  name        = "ec2_sg"
  description = "Allow HTTP, SSH, and ICMP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "ICMP"
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ec2_sg"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "publicA" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "publicB" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}


resource "aws_instance" "admin_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-0efcece6bed30fd98"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.publicA.id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "AdminInstance"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web_a" {
  ami           = "ami-0efcece6bed30fd98"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.publicA.id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "WebA"
  }
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              yum update -y
              yum install -y httpd
              systemctl enable httpd
              systemctl start httpd
              usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
              chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
              chmod 2775 /var/www
              find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
              find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
              echo "Request Handled by: WebA" >> /var/www/html/index.html
            EOF
}

resource "aws_instance" "web_b" {
  ami           = "ami-0efcece6bed30fd98"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.publicB.id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "WebB"
  }
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              yum update -y
              yum install -y httpd
              systemctl enable httpd
              systemctl start httpd
              usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
              chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
              chmod 2775 /var/www
              find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
              find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
              echo "Request Handled by: WebB" >> /var/www/html/index.html
            EOF
}

# Create new target group for the web servers
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "web_target_group" {
  name     = "web-target-group"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.balanced_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "web_a_attach" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.web_target_group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web_a.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "web_b_attach" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.web_target_group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web_b.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb" "web_nlb" {
  name               = "web-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"

  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.publicA.id,
    aws_subnet.publicB.id
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "web_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.web_nlb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.web_target_group.arn
  }
}
```

===== Edit ======

Answers to comments:

The security group now shows up in the network load balancer in both GUI and from aws cli.  The GUI is for the same region (us-west-2).

The GET request goes to the network load balancer DNS name.  The network load balancer shows a listener on port 80 that forwards to an aws_lb_target_group that contains both instances which are running.

A GET request to the public IP of my instances also hangs.  Both instances and the load balancer use the same security group, but the sg looks fine to me for http traffic on port 80.

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with your code? Does it work? If yes, what's the issue exactly?

Comment: Based on the description of the problem this is probably an issue external to TF such as a network architecture issue.

Comment: Did you check the Security group is available in GUI? Did you check in the correct AWS region/AWS account?

Comment: You are making two load balancers: both an application load balancer and a network load balancer. Which one are you sending your GET request to? Only the network load balancer would work. When you look at the network load balancer in the console, do you see that the instances show as available? What happens if you send a GET request directly to the public IP of your EC2 instances, WebA or WebB?

Comment: andyb - I've answered your questions in an edit to the OP.  The instances don't respond to a GET on their public IP addresses.  That makes me wonder if the problem is the security group which is used by both instances and the NLB.